# How to refresh a Visualforce Page Tab in Salesforce1 on salesforce1 drag down action?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

We know when we are on a Contact Tab in Salesforce1, when we want to refresh the tab we just touch our finger on screen and drag it down a bit till the circular loading action starts spinning and the Tab data is refreshed.

Now, how can we replicate same functionality on a Visualforce page such that we can refresh the page in Salesforce1 (like a custom Visualforce Tab) and that user can refresh the content in it by just dragging the screen downwards like in standard view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a javascript library to achieve this functinality. There is no native way to do this.
However for this I used this library **iScroll 5**:

Look at the following link http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/pull-to-refresh/

You can download it from  http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5

Documentation: http://iscrolljs.com/#refresh

A simple refresh implementation is given as:

```
ajax('/url', onCompletion);

function onCompletion () {
    // call action function

    setTimeout(function () {
       // can call action function or window.reload()
        myScroll.refresh();
    }, 0);
};
```

Another example:

```
// function to bind
function pullDownAction () {
    setTimeout(function () {    // <-- Simulate network congestion, remove setTimeout from production!
        myScroll.refresh();     // Remember to refresh when contents are loaded (ie: on ajax completion)
    }, 1000);   // <-- Simulate network congestion, remove setTimeout from production!
}

// Setup refresh
    var pullDownOffset = divOffsetHeight // div position
    var myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
            useTransition: true,
            topOffset: pullDownOffset,
            onRefresh: function () {
                // Show loading....
            },
        onScrollEnd: function () {
                // start rendering....
                pullDownAction();   // Execute custom function (ajax call?)
            }
        });


<div id="pullDown">
            <span class="pullDownIcon"></span><span class="pullDownLabel">Pull down to refresh...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes thanks for the info and links. I will try it but it has given me some good starting point for library to look out for :-). I've used pages inside iframe in VF pages and would like to make the page refresh on pull down action taken inside the iframe page .. but will see how it goes .. my current trouble is not to use too much of libraries as mobile app is getting slower with each new library added .. I am already using bootstrap.

Comment: @VarunC Well bootstrap is not so heavy, you can customise bootstrap to minimal required features on official website.